# On tap on suggestion in search bar not working in flutter web using flutter_typeahead package

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using [flutter_typeahead](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead): ^4.3.3 package for search bar.

When the `onChange` event is dispatched, it will call API and show suggestion on that but it's running one keyword behind the actual search and whenever I try to tap on suggestion it will not navigate to next screen.

I had try to navigate on `onSuggestionSelected`, `onTap` and `suggestionsCallback` but it will not navigate to next screen.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing with `flutter_typeahead` might be due to incorrect implementation of the `onSuggestionSelected` or `onTap` event handlers.

To correctly navigate to the next screen, you need to use the `Navigator` class in Flutter. Here's an example on how to do it using the `onSuggestionSelected` event handler:

```
TypeAheadField(
  onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => YourNextScreen(suggestion),
      ),
    );
  },
  // Other TypeAheadField properties and configurations
)
```

In the code above, `YourNextScreen` is the widget class for the next screen you want to navigate to. The `suggestion` argument is the selected `suggestion` from the `suggestions list`.

Make sure to pass the appropriate `BuildContext` to the `Navigator` and also ensure that you have set up the routing in your Flutter app.